# Interpreting notation of tensors in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, tensor-calculus, notation

I am having a really hard time wrapping my head around component notation for tensor fields. For example, I do not know exactly what the following expression means
$$\partial_\mu\partial^\nu \phi, \tag{$\#$}$$ where $\phi$ is a scalar field. On the one hand $\partial^\nu=g^{\lambda\nu}\partial_\lambda$ and hence we could write explicitly $$\partial_\mu\partial^\nu \phi=\sum_{\lambda}g^{\lambda\nu}\partial_\mu \partial_{\lambda}\phi=\begin{cases}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu& \text{ if } \nu=0\\
-\partial_\mu\partial_\nu & \text{ if }\nu=1,2,3.
\end{cases} \tag{$*$} $$
On the other hand, we may think of $\partial_\mu\partial^\nu=g(\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu)=\delta_\mu^\nu;$ so that $\partial_\mu\partial^\nu\phi=\phi?$ Maybe? I am actually not sure of what this would mean. I am really confused. Any help is appreciated.

To give context of where this expression comes from: I was computing the Lagrangian $$\mathcal L=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu\phi)(\partial^\mu \phi) $$ considering an infinitesimal spacetime translation $x^ \mu\to x^\mu-\alpha a^\mu$. The scalar field thus transforms like $\phi(x)\to \phi(x)+\alpha(\partial_\mu\phi(x))a^\mu.$
Plugging thins into the Lagrangian yields the term I am referring to.

I do not have any background in using indices to talk about tensors. I am used to interpret the expressions $\partial_\mu$ as the local vector field defined in some chart (local coordinates) that to each point assigns the corresponding basis tangent vector of its tangent space. I think about vector fields $X$ as abstract secction of the Tangent bundle, which restricted to local coordinates can be expressed as $X=X^\mu\partial_\mu$. In the context of QFT, as far as I understand, the symbol $\partial_\mu$ denotes  $(\partial_t,\nabla)$ in the local coordinates $(t,x,y,z)$. So that $\partial_\mu\phi=(\partial_t \phi,\partial_x \phi,\partial_y\phi,\partial_z\phi)$. Finally I think of $g^{\mu \nu}$ as the component ($\mu\nu$) of the matrix $$g=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&0&0&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
which represents the pseudo-Riemmanian metric, which by definition acts on tangent vectors, i.e. linear combinations of the $\partial_\mu$ applied to a point. This is where my second strange interpratation of ($\#$) comes from. My question is thus: What is the right way to interpret the component-index notation; and in particular what is the expresion $(\#)$ in explicit coordinates?

Comment: I'm not sure but your confusion may come from the fact that $\partial_\mu \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$ for derivatives, while $\partial_\mu$ in $g(\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu)=\eta_{\mu \nu}$ is a vector of the basis of the minkoswki space-time. By the way your statment $g(\partial_\mu,\partial_\nu)=\delta_\mu^\nu$ is not true. To have upper indices you have to take the value of $g$ for the dual of $\partial_\mu$, namely $dx^\mu$.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/582232/2451

Comment: Hi JerryCastilla. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: I did, but it is still closed and I have no clue why.

Comment: Closed questions which are edited are put in a queue to be voted on by the community for reopening.  Sometimes they are, sometimes they are not.  You have to wait and if it is not reopened by the community you cannot circumvent that by posting a duplicate (or near duplicate) question.